# Is docker a possible solution to ruby GIL limitation in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

This is just an idea, let me know if I'm missing anything or if it could be a good one.

It's common to have N rails processes running on a single server/VM, but they can't perform at best due GIL (Global Interpreter Lock).

Instead of running N processes inside a single server I could run N containers each one with a single rails process (each one running on a different port).

In this way I should be able to execute more rails processes in parallel, right?

I guess containers add overhead but probably it could make sense anyway.

Any opinions?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This would be far less efficient than running N processes. The simple reason here is that most process managers for Ruby on Rails use the "pre-fork" model where a large amount of code is loaded in before the processes are split off.

A `fork` of two process uses very little additional memory, the second process inherits a near exact copy of the first. Any changes made to this will incur more memory overhead, but as things like the Rails library and other gems are not changed, that comes along for free, basically.

If you had multiple processes that are independent, each would need to load, parse, and initialize every Ruby class necessary to run Rails.

This isn't to say that the container-ized approach isn't without merit, but it may necessitate a hybrid approach: N containers with M processes each.

Remember, if you're really having trouble with the GIL, just use [Jruby](http://jruby.org/) which doesn't have one.

Comment: The main problem I see with Jruby is that many gems don't support it (but honestly my last tests were some time ago so maybe situation changed).

You are right about fork, I would be curious to understand how much memory would be wasted (due duplication in different containers).

Yes, probably N containers with M processes could be a good trade-off.

Comment: In addition, when you use a concurrent web server such as Unicorn, Thin, Puma, etc. You already have multiple Rails process or threads running. This is ideal when running a monolithic Rails app since the processes share memory as @tadman mentioned. However, in service oriented architectures where you have pieces of the app in that run separately maybe do to varying scaling concerns the container approach could have its merits if done right.

Comment: @SDp Jruby support is much better than it used to be, so it's worth testing again. There are some legacy libraries that will never be supported, they're way too tied to the MRI version, but there's usually more modern alternatives that are more agnostic.

Answer (score 1):

This won't improve concurrency at all: the GIL applies to threads within a single process. Multiple processes can already execute concurrently - the pattern of having multiple rails processes arises because of the GIL.

As tadman says, you'll also potentially increase memory usage. You might be able to estimate it (assuming you deploy using passenger) as the passenger-memory-stats tool allows you to get RSS as well as private dirty RSS (i.e. memory that is resident, but not shared with the parent process). If the non shared memory is almost none then you wouldn't waste any by following a non fork model.

Containers are wonderful things, but what you've outlined isn't a reason to use them.

Comment: I will try to check RSS, thanks! I got what you said, it was an idea but now it looks not as good as at the beginning :)